# Display opening hours for the current day with a shortcode in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm pretty new to PHP, but I've written this code which grabs the current day of the week and displays the opening hours for that day. This was working ok when included in the header of my WP site.

```
<?php
$openingHours = [
'Mon' => "Today we're open 8.30am – 6:30pm",
'Tue' => "Today we're open 8.30am – 6:30pm",
'Wed' => "Today we're open 8.30am – 6:30pm",
'Thu' => "Today we're open 8.30am – 6:30pm",
'Fri' => "Today we're open 8.30am - 6:30pm",
'Sat' => "Today we're open 8.30am – 3:00pm",
'Sun' => "Today we're closed"
];
$day_today = date('D');
?>
<div class="openingHours">
<?php echo $openingHours[$day_today];?>
</div>
```

I want to add this as a shortcode in wordpress so I can place it anywhere on the page, though can't seem to get it to work at all..

This is what I've got at the moment:

```
function pet_hours () {
echo $openinghours[$day_today];
$day_today = date('D');
$openinghours = [
'Mon' => "Today we're open 8.30am – 6:30pm",
'Tue' => "Today we're open 8.30am – 6:30pm",
'Wed' => "Today we're open 8.30am – 6:30pm",
'Thu' => "Today we're open 8.30am – 6:30pm",
'Fri' => "Today we're open 8.30am - 6:30pm",
'Sat' => "Today we're open 8.30am – 3:00pm",
'Sun' => "We are closed today"];
}
add_shortcode( 'pet_hours' );
```

Where am I going wrong??

Comment: You're trying to `echo $openinghours[$day_today];` before either the `$openinghours` array and the `$day_today` variable have been defined.

Comment: also - you need a name for the shortcode - example `add_shortcode( 'yourShortCodeName, 'your_function' );` - both of these are required

Comment: You may have more help for that on the site for WordPress development questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com